# Delete feature selection using Python (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

I'm having some issues with a Python script for ArcGIS 10. The idea is to delete points from a single shapefile according to the values of two columns ("Tracks" and "Tracks_1"). 
Therefore, I want to:

1. Select features who share a certain ID
2. Unselect some of the features depending on their values
3. Delete the remaining selection from the shapefile
4. Proceed with the next ID

.

```
import arcpy
env.overwriteOutput = True
centroids_thinned="O:\\centroids_thinned.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(centroids_thinned, "centroids_thinned_layer")
rows=arcpy.SearchCursor(centroids_thinned)
for row in rows:
    ID_centroids = row.getValue("FID_centro")
    ID_buffer = row.getValue("FID_cent_1")
    Tracks_centroids = row.getValue("Tracks")
    Tracks_buffer = row.getValue("Tracks_1")
    if ID_buffer == ID_centroids:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("centroids_thinned_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "FID_centro = " + str(ID_buffer))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("centroids_thinned_layer", "REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION","FID_centro = FID_cent_1")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("centroids_thinned_layer", "REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION","Tracks_1 > " +  str(Tracks_centroids))
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("centroids_thinned_layer").getOutput(0))
        if count > 0:
                arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("centroids_thinned_layer")
                print str(count) + " Attributes Deleted."
```

The selection process works fine but for some reason those selected features are not deleted from the attribute table. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are the 5 lines after `if ID_buffer == ID_centroids:` really at the same indentation level as that statement?

Comment: No. That must have happened when i copied the code. I'm gonna correct that. Thanks.

Comment: When you say the selection process works fine, how exactly do you know that? Is it simply not crashing, or are you actually inspecting the values of `count`?

Comment: Yes, I was inspecting the `count` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the time right now to revise your code, but I think your problem is that you're trying to delete features from the very same shapefile you're in the middle of looping through (albeit as a feature layer).

I would suggest that you only call `arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management()` once, after the search cursor has gone through the entire thing; you can keep track of all of the features to delete as the cursor progresses using a python list, and then construct a query to re-select and delete them all in one go at the end.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. DeleteFeatures doesn't work when it's within a SearchCursor.

Answer (score 2):

Like @nmpeterson said, it's likely because you're doing this: open SearchCursor on centroids_thinned.shp, you run DeleteFeatures *while* your searchCursor is still open on centroids_thinned.shp.

I don't know exactly what your data looks like, but a common approach is to open a [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/) and get the records sorted based on some fields (for you it's Tracks & Tracks_1).

```
sql_clause  = ('','ORDER BY ID_centroids, ID_buffer ')
```

Then basically keeping track of when the values change from the previous record to determine if it meets your "delete" criteria or not.